# How can I see elements and sources as a split window/separate windows?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm using [chrome resource mapping](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3) to create/modify my .scss, and my work flow is using the element picker to find the element I'm looking at, then modifying it in my source files.

Can I have both panels open at the same time?